# Transit at PEK international aiport T3

Tags: transit, airports, beijing

I'm an Indian citizen travelling from DXB to Ulaanbatar (UBN) via PEK. I have boooked tickets with Emirates (DXB-PEK) and (PEK-UBN) with MIAT Mongolian airlines respectively. Both are independent bookings.

It seems both airlines are operating in T3 and there's a 6-hour transit time. Does the 24-hour free transit in PEK allow you to go collect check-in luggage via immigration? Do we need to apply for an entry permit?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is whether Emirates and MIAT interline (which I doubt, though). If they do, you can check in your luggage all the way. If they don't, which is probable, you'll indeed have to pick up your luggage and check in again.

That's what the 24-hour transit is for. If you're eligible (can't remember offhand whether Indian citizens are, I'll check), you'll be able to enter China on this visa exemption.